# Migrations are stuck

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, migration

It looks to me like all ELU migrations elsewhither are stuck, and have been so for a day or so. This includes any migrations from ELU to ELL as well as here to our own Meta.

What's happening is they get closed for being offtopic as belonging on another site, then locked, but then those migrations are never picked up by the internal job (software agent) that actually migrates them to their destination.

This has happened once before, quite a few years ago now. I’m posting here, and with these tags, upon CM request so that it gets queued up for fixing by the SE ops team.

#### Recent examples from [this query](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3a1%20locked%3a1%20migrated%3a0%20duplicate%3a0):

1. [Ignore this: migration testing only](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597568/ignore-this-migration-testing-only)
2. [We want to know which type of design users like the most to focus on](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597567/we-want-to-know-which-type-of-design-users-like-the-most-to-focus-on)
3. [Is the Grammar wrong](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597555/is-the-grammar-wrong)
4. [How to politely say "you have to decide quickly"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597535/how-to-politely-say-you-have-to-decide-quickly)
5. [What is easy english book you would recommend me to read? (for ESL)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597488/what-is-easy-english-book-you-would-recommend-me-to-read-for-esl)
6. [Why is the singular "dress" used in "all wearing traditional dress"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597468/why-is-the-singular-dress-used-in-all-wearing-traditional-dress)
7. [What does the line "they'll be sorry they bought come sun up" from Deadwood mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/597356/what-does-the-line-theyll-be-sorry-they-bought-come-sun-up-from-deadwood-mean)

Comment: The first one was [reposted on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/326232/41273), so there's not really a benefit to migrating it now. Not sure what can be done without messing things up further though.

Comment: @Laurel The real problem is that the entire migration mechanism is all jammed up, whether to ELL or anywhere else. See the linked query in my update. Once it gets unjammed, we can attend to any consequences in case of duplication.

Comment: Marked as [meta-tag:status-planned] on MSE: [All question migrations are currently broken across the entire SE network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383353/all-question-migrations-are-currently-broken-across-the-entire-se-network)

Answer (score 4):

(Copying in [my answer from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383393/51))

---

We had a site-to-site post migrations outage from sometime mid-afternoon UTC on October 27 through late morning UTC on October 30 (a little under 3 days). This is now fixed.

The actual outage was caused by some changes made to our internal network configuration. Site-to-site migrations work via API calls between sites that are configured to never leave our data center, and the changes that were made prevented these calls from going through successfully. These changes have been reversed.

This leaves nearly 3 days of site-to-site post migrations that were not performed. We are currently evaluating ways to proceed with going about performing this backfill network-wide, and will update here when we have more information to share.

**Update:**

- The Stack Overflow mods manually went through the 8 posts that were up for migration during this outage, and made decisions on them whether to manually migrate or not
- As for the rest of the network (where there are on average 14 migrations daily for all non-SO sites combined), we have made the decision to not put in a backfill for this. The logic needed for the backfill is actually quite complicated and unreliable (each one would need to be manually checked anyway, especially after some mods have already gone ahead and made decisions on migrate/not for all affected posts), and is not worth the investment of time to implement for a one-time event like this.
- Thus, for the approximately 50 affected posts across the network during this 3-day period, we will leave it up to mods of individual sites to act on individual affected posts and will not be performing any automated actions. Affected posts will stay closed-as-off-topic on their originating sites (and mods can manually override this and migrate them if they so choose).